Bridge: Feedback on questionable convention card
Sorry in advance if such questions are not allowed. I specifically want feedback on whether there are any inconsistencies / misinterpretations in my approach, and whether I need to add anything else for this to constitute a legal convention card. I am attending an international competition (held by China's CCBA) for the first time.


Raw OCR:
DEFENSIVE AND COMPETITIVE BIDDING
OVERCALLS (Style: Responses: 1 / 2 Level; Reopening)
level overcalls promise 8 HCP while 2 level overcalls promise 10.
Both overcalls are used with (not necessarily good) 5+ card suits.
(1m) -
- 2m is a valid 2 level overcall.
No weak overcalls in the reopening position are allowed.
INT OVERCALL (2"*/4th Live; Responses; Reopening)
Equivalent to INT opening but promises stopper in overcalled suit.
No weak overcalls in the reopening position are allowed.
JUMP OVERCALLS (Style; Responses; Unusual NT)
Pre-emptive - that is, 6 cards for level 2, 7 cards for 3, etc., ≤10 HCP. 2NT overcall is equivalent to 2NT opening.
No transferring is done with jump overcalls.
Reopen: No change
DIRECT & JUMP CUE BIDS (Style; Response; Reopen)
(1m) - 2m and (1m) -
- 3m are valid overcalls, not cue bids.
(1M) - 2M is equivalent to a takeout double with 15+ HCP.
(1M) - 3M is not allowed.
VS. NT (vs. Strong/Weak; Reopening; PH)
2 level overcalls are natural - 10+ HCP and good 5+ card suit.
3 level jump overcalls are standard pre-emptive: see jump overcalls
(INT) - X is equivalent to opening INT (1NT) - 2NT is not allowed.
VS.PREEMTS (Doubles; Cue-bids; Jumps; NT Bids)
Doubles are takeout doubles with 15+ HCP: see takeout doubles
2NT overcall is equivalent to 2NT opening with 18+ HCP.
(2X) - (3X) is not allowed. Overcalls are 12+ HCP and good 5+ suits.
VS. ARTIFICIAL STRONG OPENINGS- i.e., 1% or 2% Standard defences still apply. Doubling a strong 1C is not allowed.
We do not interfere with 2C.
OVER OPPONENTS' TAKEOUT DOUBLE
Pass is weakest. Any other action increases your HCP lower bound by 1.
Otherwise, nothing changes. Forcing bids are normally still forcing.
LEADS AND SIGNALS
OPENING LEADS STYLE
With 4 cards or more, lead the top card if there are ≥ 3 honors or AK, and lead the lowest card otherwise.
With 3 cards, lead top card with the top two cards connected (e.g., QJx, 76x)
Else lead second highest with no HCP in suit, and otherwise the lowest card.
With a doubleton, lead the top card.
When in doubt, lead with the safer major.
LEADS
Lead
Ace
King
Queen
Jack
10
Situation
AK(+) / ≥3 honors with A / Ax
KQx / ≥3 honors with K without A / Kx
QJx / Qx
J10x / Jx
109x / 10x
9×
98x /9x
X followed by connected card, and then a smaller card OR Xx OR xXx, where no card is strictly above 10.
SIGNALS IN ORDER OF PRIORITY
Partner's Lead
Declarer's Lead
Low like high hate.
Low like high hate.
Suit 2 Ambiguous signals are Ambiguous signals are
3 probably not signals.
probably not signals.
Low like high hate.
Low like high hate.
NT 2 Ambiguous signals are Ambiguous signals are
3 probably not signals.
probably not signals.
Discarding
Low like high hate.
Ambiguous signals are probably not signals.
Low like high hate.
Amolzuous sianals are probably not signals.
Signals including Trumps):
Playing low from connected cards is not assumed.
DOUBLES
TAKEOUT DOUBLES (Style; Responses; Reopening)
Promises 3 cards in each of the 3 unbid suits / 4 cards in each of 2 unbid suits / 5 cards in the only unbid suit and 12 HCP / 10 HCP if partner promises 12.
OR 17+ with a good 5-card suit (follow up with suit)
OR 17+ balanced (follow up with NT)
SPECIAL, ARTIFICIAL & COMPETITIVE DBLS/RDLS
Doubles under (not including) 2NT are all takeout doubles except for
(INT) - X which is equivalent to opening INT.
Redoubles towards non-penalty doubles signify at least 2 HCP above the established HCP lower bound (or 8 HCP, if there is no such bound).
Example. 1H - (X) - XX is 8+ HCP, and 1H - 2D - (X) - XX is 14+ HCP.
Doubles on CAPP 2C overcalls on 1NT are negative (Stayman).
W B F CONVENTION CARD
CATEGORY: i.e., Green / Blue / Red / HUM / Brown Sticker: Red
PLAYERS：陆畅 Chang Lu，唐铭泽 Mingze Tang
SYSTEM SUMMARY
GENERAL APPROACH AND STYLE
Chang is generally aggressive and Mingze is more conservative.
Pre-empting style correlates heavily with vulnerability.
With favorable vulnerability pre-empting can deviate by 2 HCP
Or 1 card.
The system is highly natural, with minimal artificial bids.
INT opening - good 14 HCP to 17 HCP.
2/1 FG.
1X - 2NT is force to game.
SPECIAL BIDS THAT MAY REQUIRE DEFENSE
2m / 3m overcalling 1m is not a cue bid, but a regular overcall.
2M overcalling 1M is equivalent to takeout double with 15+ HCP
SPECIAL FORCING PASS SEQUENCES
None - we do not use forcing pass.
IMPORTANT NOTES
If unsure, we assume a bid to be natural.
PSYCHICS:

OPENING
1%
19
14
INT
20
20
20
24
2NT
320
3NT
400
4.
4A
4NT
5%
50
TICK IN
ARTIFICIAL
MIN. NO. OF CARDS
3
None.
None.
None.
None.
None.
DESCRIPTION
12-21 HCP. Prefers longer minor.
3-3 is 1C but 4-4 or above is 1D.
12-21 HCP. Prefers longer major.
5-5 or above is 1S.
Good 14-17 HCP and balanced.
OR ≤ 3 HCP in third position.
≥22 HCP OR can play 3NT.
6-10 HCP.
Minimum quality: QTxxxx
Same as 2D.
Same as 2D.
20-21 HCP and balanced.
≤10 HCP, min quality: Qxxxxxx
Same as 3C.
Same as 3D.
Same as 3H.
There is no minimum quality.
Has 9 sure winners but lacks control.
Also promises a good 6+ suit.
≤10 HCP, has another 4-card suit
OR has 8+ cards in that suit.
To play.
To play.
RKCB. Wants NT slam.
To play.
To play.
RKCB eliminating H. Wants slam with trump.
Same as 5H.
RESPONSES
IC - 1D is ART GF and interested in 4-4 major.
Im - 2NT is ART GF and aims for 3NT.
1M is standard 1/1, 1D - 2C is standard 2/1.
1m - 2m is F3m with 10+ HCP, 5+m.
Standard 1/1 and 2/1 still apply.
1M - 2NT is ART GF and aims for 3NT.
2C is major Stayman and 2S is minor Stayman.
2D, 2H, 2NT, 3C, 3D, 3H, 4D, 4H transfer to the next bid.
3S is 15+ and wants 6NT or above. 4NT is RKCB. 2D is <8 HCP, 2M is natural with 5+M >8 HCP.
2NT is >8 HCP otherwise. 3NT is hopeless ≤2 HCP.
3D/4D is 3/4+ D pre-emptive and 5D is to play.
2NT ASK for HCP (28) and quality (AK/KQ/AQ).
3H is 3+ H pre-emptive and 4H is to play.
2NT ASK for HCP (≥6) and quality (AK/KQ/AQ). 3C is major Stayman (≥4 HCP). 3D, 3H, 4D, 4H transfers.
3S is 10+ and wants 6NT or above. 4NT is RKCB.
4C is 3+ C pre-emptive and 5C is to play.
4H is to play.
Pass (to play) promises control in two suits. Else 4C/4D.
4D promises ~6 HCP (~2 tricks) and no voids / singletons.
Any response except ?C to play is high level bidding
Respond with RKCB (see high level bidding).
Respond with RKCB (see high level bidding).
(Ignore king in trump suit since trump is unspecified.)
SUBSEQUENT ACTION
1C - 1D auctions sequences proceed like 1/1.
1m - 2NT starts cue bidding at the third level.
Any four level bid after 1m - 2NT is natural to play.
1M - 2NT proceeds the same way as 1m - 2NT.
INT - 2C - 2D - 2M is 5+ M. Do not Stayman with 4-3-3-3. 2S is replied with 2NT (15-bad 16) or 3C/3D/3NT (good 16-17).
3S starts cue bidding of any round control in level 4.
Subsequent action is natural.
2D - 2NT - 3C/3D/3H/3S is
No-No / Yes-No / No-Yes / Yes-Yes
COMPETITIVE & PASSED
HAND BIDDING
2/1 by passed hand is 10-11 HCP.
This applies to 1C - 1D auctions.
Passed hand bidding 3S is natural.
2NT - 3C - 3D - 3M is 5+ oM. Do not Stayman with 4-3-3-3.
3S starts cue bidding of any round control in level 4. 3C and above does not have an equivalent for 2S - 2NT.
4C can be responded with 4C (pass) / 4D / 4H / 4S.
4D can be responded with 4H / 4S / 5C/ 5D.
HIGH LEVEL BIDDING
Any level 4 bid is a cue bid signifying second round control, unless explicitly otherwise.
Any level 5 bid, unless explicitly otherwise, is RKCB eliminating aces in that suit.
If a level 5 bid is m trump, it is to play, and if it is M trump, it is invitation to small slam.
4NT calls are always RKCB (1/4, 0/3, 2, 2Q), except QI in INT sequences.
4NT RKCB in NT contexts are replied with (1/4, 0/3, 2).
5NT calls are always ASK for partner's non-trump K location.
(Call the lowest K location or return to trump suit (NT in NT context) if not available.)


Sorry in advance if such questions are not allowed. I specifically want feedback on whether there are any inconsistencies / misinterpretations in my approach, and whether I need to add anything else for this to constitute a legal convention card.

Please edit all clarifications into the original question. Comment threads are ephemeral, and may be deleted at any time.  I suspect this question is currently far (far) too broad, and likely to get closed on that account. If you can narrow things down to a specific feature you think may be questionable, and clarify as to what Law Authority you are playing under (ACBL, WBF, EBU, or some other), that will make the question much more tractable for this site.

Edited, thank u for ur time

Still far too broad. This is just "review my card plz" which is both a significant task and does not help anybody else in future at all.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Specifically, what are your concerns? Quick review (NOT an answer): it looks more detailed than many CCs at top-level events, and many quirks are spelled out clearly.  I would have no issues understanding it as an opponent (though you might get a lot of questions, because of those many quirks.  But I ask a lot of questions).

The only people who can effectively answer solely "is this acceptable" are the organizers of the tournament.  If you have concerns, submit it to them.
Unless you have specific questions that can be answered from regulations or from "would I as an opponent understand this sequence, or would I throw the CC on the floor as useless?", only the tournament has any authoritative say.
